# iOS WebView CanGoBack BUG

Tags: ios, uiwebview

[image]

Why for the first time into the webview, canGoBack defaults to yes？

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Bug , that's how the website was built , it redirects to "https://book.douban.com/subject/26728018/#!/i!/ckDefault" , so the web view can go back is true.